# Heapifying an array with duplicates

Tags: data-structures, heap

I was trying to heapify an array. My code is working fine with an array of unique values. But had a problem with duplicate entries.The maximum value is always achieved at the root. Yet, the result is not a heap.

CODE:

```
static int arr[7] = { 5, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7 };
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  
    for (int i = (6 - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--)//assuming size 7(0 to 6)
    {
        heapify2(i);
    }
    return 0;
}

void heapify2(int key)
{
    int nextchoice = (arr[2 * key + 1] > arr[2 * key + 2] ? (2 * key + 1) : (2 * key + 2));
    if (arr[key] < arr[nextchoice])
    {
        arr[key] += arr[nextchoice];
        arr[nextchoice] = arr[key] - arr[nextchoice];
        arr[key] = arr[key] - arr[nextchoice];
    }
}
```

RESULTANT HEAP:
7,6,5,4,1,3,7

Here, last node 7 comes under 5.
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please note that I edited your code sample to fix the formatting. Next time, use spaces rather than tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that on your last iteration it's swapping the 5 and the 7, giving:

```
7,6,5,4,1,3,7
```

5 is still out of place. You need to *continue* checking until you know that 5 is in the proper place. So your `heapify` needs to be run in a loop:

```
while (key < length/2)
{
    nextchoice = ....
    if (arr[key] < arr[nextchoice])
    {
        ...
    }
    key = nextchoice
}
```

Also, your outer loop really should start at `length/2`. In this case `(7/2)`, which will start at 3 rather than 2. It's not a problem in this case, but it's possible that with other arrangements of items, failing to check that middle item will cause a problem.

Comment: When I start with middle element rather than (middle-1), it has to check an element that doesn't have any child. Consider the heap size is 8, the loop would start at (( size-1) -1) / 2 = 3.Only if the size is 8 or more, the third element has the child.